# Chapter without number in memoir

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir, chapters

I want one of the chapters in my `memoir` book to be unnumbered.

I want it to have a chapter heading, show up in the table of contents, etc.--the only difference being that it is not given a number.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\chapter*{Your chapter title}` to get an unnumbered chapter, but it will also not include that chapter in the ToC.  So you can then say `\addtocontents{toc}{Your chapter title}` to add the chapter title manually.

Comment: This was the correct answer, but I had to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Your chapter title}` instead of `\addtocontents{toc}{Your chapter title}`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you do not want any numbering at all

```
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\maxsecnumdepth{none}
```

then just use `\chapter` as normal

Comment: Thanks!  But now every subsequent chapter is also unnumbered--I want to unnumber just one chapter in the middle of the book.

Comment: Then reset those two macros after the chapter. (The `\maxsecnumdepth` is only needed for stuff before `\mainmatter`)